# Conditional logging by final status code

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, syslog

I'm trying to log apache request errors to syslog, but I'm having trouble with the conditional logging. There doesn't seem to be a variable that contains the final status code. This is what I have now:

```
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -thttpd -plocal6.notice" "%h \"%{PHPSESSID}C\" \"%m %>s %U%q\" \"%Dms\"" "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS}=~/^4/"
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -thttpd -plocal6.warning" "%h \"%{PHPSESSID}C\" \"%m %>s %U%q\" \"%Dms\"" "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS}=~/^5/"
```

This doesn't work, because `%{REQUEST_STATUS}` doesn't contain the final status code, and at the point of evaluation it always seems to be 200 for requests handled by php-fpm. I tried `%{LA-U:REQUEST_STATUS}` as described in the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), but that results in a syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_ERROR, expecting T_VAR_END or ':': Invalid character in variable name '-'
```

How can I resolve this?